# Init a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, init, c-preprocessor

I have a question related to struct initialization in C.
I have a struct:

```
struct TestStruct
{
u8 status;
u8 flag1;
u8 flag2;
};
```

I want a generic function/macro to initialize this struct and set the value of one parameter, eg status =1, easy way is:

```
TestStruct t = {};
t.status = 1;
```

However, by doing this I have set the value of status twice, first to 0 in init function and second set it to 1 (optimization does not help?).
(Please dont tell me t = {1,0,0} Im looking for a generic way)
I am thinking about a macro in init function, something like:

```
#define INIT_TESTSTRUCT (param, value) \
{ .status=0, .flag1=0, .flag2=0, .param=value }
TestStruct t = INIT_TESTSTRUCT(status, 0);
```

However, the compiler gives error  "initialized field overwritten", because I have set the value of status twice.

Please help to point out how to alter the macro to achieve what I want, many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
#define INIT_TESTSTRUCT(param, value) \
    { .param=(value) }
TestStruct t = INIT_TESTSTRUCT(status, 0);
```

should do it. The variable is then added in `.data` segment - as it is an initialized one - and all fields which are not mentionned explicitly are set to 0 by the compiler (instead of the linker or the loader).

Comment: Thanks man, this helps me to understand struct init function :)

Comment: Shouldn't value be in () brackets? I'm not sure if lack of them can break anything, but it's always good to be safe.

Comment: You are right, `value` should have `()` around it for the case it contains confusing stuff, but in the case of `param`, it would be conterproductive.

Comment: @DarthHunterix Normally, you put `()` if you have a macro which could be put into a function: `#define TWICE(x) (2*(x))`. In this case, `TWICE(2 + 2)` yields `(2*(2+2))` which is fine. With a mere `2*x` you could do `~TWICE(2+2)` which would yield `~2*2+2` which would rather mean `((~2)*2)+2`, not at all the intended thing.

Answer (score 2):

You have a space in the wrong place:

```
#define INIT_TESTSTRUCT(param, value) \
{ .status=0, .flag1=0, .flag2=0, .param=(value) }
```

should do it.

The `(` of the macro definition must come immediately after the macro name. Otherwise the parser takes this as a macro with no arguments and expands it to `(param, value) ...etc...` and in your case this then obviously is a syntax error.

Also note that it is usually a good idea to put `()` around parameters in the replacment text, to avoid syntax confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly

```
TestStruct t = {};
```

is illegal in C. If it compiled in your case, it must be a non-standard compiler extension. You can achieve the same effect by

```
TestStruct t = { 0 };
```

which is legal in C. It sets *all* fields in the entire struct to zeros.

Secondly, even with designated initializers C language follows the traditional *"all-or-nothing"* approach to initialization: if you initialize just one field of the aggregate, all other fields are implicitly initialized to zero.

Which means that in your case all you have to do is

```
TestStruct t = { .status = 1 };
```

to initialize the entire struct. `status` field will be set to `1`, while all other fields will be set to zero.

So, your macro can be implemented as

```
#define INIT_TESTSTRUCT(param, value) { .param = value }
TestStruct t = INIT_TESTSTRUCT(status, 1);
```

There's no need to explicitly set all other fields to zero - it will happen by itself.